# animated border not connecting at corner

Tags: html, css

I had this working the other day, but I've rewritten the code a few times to get all my animations working and styles displaying, and now for some reason, these animated borders aren't connecting at three of the corners. Can someone please tell me what has gotten lost in translation?

```css
.desktopNav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.desktopNav li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1.7em;
}

.desktopNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222323;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.hoverbox::before,
.hoverbox::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.hoverbox::before,
.hoverbox::after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f7941e;
}

.hoverbox::before {
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.hoverbox::after {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.hoverbox:hover::before,
.hoverbox:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
  <ul class="menu desktopNav">

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">home</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">about</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">services</a></li>
  </div>


  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">work</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">process</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">contact</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have two `</div>` in your list where they don't belong.

Comment: that got messed up between the file, the codepen, and here. Good catch though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `box-sizing`.

```
.hoverbox::before,
    .hoverbox::after {
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #f7941e;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```css
.desktopNav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.desktopNav li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1.7em;
}

.desktopNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222323;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.hoverbox::before,
.hoverbox::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.hoverbox::before,
.hoverbox::after {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f7941e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hoverbox::before {
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.hoverbox::after {
  border-width: 0 2px 0 2px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.hoverbox:hover::before,
.hoverbox:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
  <ul class="menu desktopNav">

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">home</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">about</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">services</a></li>
  </div>


  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">work</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">process</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="hoverbox">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot the box-sizing in the new file. Thank you so much! I would've racked my brain for days and never caught that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to fix it:

A working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/p4cv3cez/

```
.hoverbox::before, .hoverbox::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.hoverbox::before, .hoverbox::after {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f7941e;
}
.hoverbox::before {
    border-width: 0 0 0 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
.hoverbox::after {
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
.hoverbox:hover::before, .hoverbox:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: That's a different hover effect, but I do like that a lot.